# Download an entire site folder via ftp using terminal on a mac

Tags: macos, command-line, ftp, terminal

Lets say for kicks that my site ftp login details are:

100.100.10.100
username
password

What is the best (fastest download with a relatively simple syntax) method to download an entire site folder (including all sub folders) via ftp using terminal on a mac? Using strictly default out of the box tools in 10.8 - without having to install extra tools please.

Please don't suggest wget - I'm failing miserably with installing it for mysterious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SFTP.  Should be enabled by default.

sftp -r user@host:directory

Man page: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sftp.1.html

Comment: SFTP may totally not be enabled by default depending on what server the user is connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tell you that the default ftp can't get files recursively. You could use shell to do it. But I sugguest you try lftp (not wget ^_^)

Comment: Okay, thanks that's noted. but i'm crossing my fingers hoping there might be some other way.

Answer (score 0):

If sftp is not enabled, you can try [ftpcopy](http://ohse.de/uwe/ftpcopy.html)

I never tried to use it on mac, but [it claims to compile on it](http://ohse.de/uwe/ftpcopy/NEWS.html)